# How to add a storybook knob that is a shape, therefore expects an object and then a boolean

Tags: javascript, reactjs, storybook

I want to add a Knob that displays a boolean which I can click on and mark it as "isCompleted" or not.

Comment: A shape is just an object, so just put the knob inside an object. `itemTypeData: { isComplete: boolean(/**/)}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`object` knob](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/tree/master/addons/knobs#object):

```
itemTypeData: object('itemTypeData', { isCompleted: true })
```

You could also define a separate `boolean` knob for `isCompleted` and toggle it using `updateKnob`:

```
const isCompleted = boolean('isCompleted', false);
...
itemTypeData: object('itemTypeData', { isCompleted })
```

Then, just add `updateKnob('isCompleted', !isCompleted)` to whatever `onClick` handler you're using.